# Add the correct condition in WHERE statement using CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It's been months since I explore SQL Server but I am still new to this field. I need to output rows that will return `ISBLANK = 0` or `ISBLANK IS NULL`. I am using `CASE` statement.

Expected output:

[image]

My code:

```
SELECT UD.FID
    , UD.UID
    , CBH.BID
    , FBA.ISBLANK
FROM TEMP_UD UD
INNER JOIN TBL_CBH CBH
    ON UD.FID = CBH.FID
INNER JOIN TBL_UDF UDF
    ON UDF.FID = UDF.FID
LEFT JOIN TBL_FBA FBA
    ON FBA.FID = CBH.FID
    AND FBA.BID = CBH.BID
WHERE
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN UDF.COND = 10 AND UDF.UID = 12 AND FBA.ISBLANK != 1
                THEN 0
        END = FBA.ISBLANK
    )
```

Current output:

```
FID UID BID ISBLANK
-------------------
1   12  1   0
1   12  1   0
```

Sample code:

https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3y29djktg

Comment: `CASE` expressions should rarely be using in a `WHERE`, and especially not on columns. Use `AND` and `OR` logic to attempt to maintain as much SARGability as possible.

Comment: Also `CASE` is an **expression** in T-SQL; it returns a scalar value. T-SQL has no support for `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CASE WHEN UDF.COND = 10
       AND UDF.UID = 12
       AND FBA.ISBLANK = 1
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END = 1
```

This will/should return the rows where `ISBLANK 1 1` does not apply.

I am wondering why you are not using the conditions directly in the WHERE, like this:

```
WHERE UDF.COND = 10
AND UDF.UID = 12
AND ( FBA.ISBLANK IS NULL OR FBA.ISBLANK = 0 )
```

If any optimizations can be made based on the columns that are used, they cannot be made if they are used in a CASE expression.